# Loss of "Reviewers" identities in Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2007

In Word 2007, when I save a document with Tracked Changes, Word looses the identities of the individual Reviewers and indicates that all Tracked changes were made by "Author".

Answer (score 0):

Probably the issue is due to some security settings.

Click the Office button and select **Word Options** | **Trust Center** | **Trust Center Settings** | **Privacy Options**. Look for **Document-specific settings group** and  uncheck **Remove personal information from file properties on save**

If the option is grayed out hover the mouse over the option to see an explanation for this reason.

If the document was created in Word 2003 and saved **Remove personal information from file properties on save** option checked, you should be able to uncheck it in Word 2007, but it won't bring back the author information that was already lost, but any later tracked changes will be saved.

[image: This is from Word-2010 but should be the same as in Word-2007]

For Office-2003 users:

Go to **Tools** | **Options** | **Security** and uncheck **Remove personal information from file properties on save**